# Combining an SSL cert and a js script into one file

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to combine the SSL cert I got from GoDaddy with a JavaScript file I have saved. I'm trying to run them together on port 443.

Comment: Why do they need to be combined into one file? That doesn't seem to match the described goal.

Comment: If they don't I would be happy to find out how to do it. Someone told me to set up my SSL in nginx and put that in front of the host server. But I have no idea how to do that. Do you have any suggestions? My problem is the SSL is listening on port 443 so I can't add anything else to that unless they are combined somehow into one application.

Answer (score 0):

For an normal webserver, the initial transaction which utilizes SSL occurs before any JavaScript file is passed, so in this case it likely wouldn't be possible to "combine" the two.

However, I noticed you have tagged this question as `node.js`. Assuming you are trying to run a web application of some sort that uses HTTPS, while it isn't "combining" anything, you would likely need to pass the location of your certificate and key files as variables to the application prior to starting your server to allow the JavaScript file (application) to utilize them for HTTPS transactions. The process of loading or preparing these files for use in your script would depend on how you were creating the application (e.g. Express.js, [restify.js](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/), homebrew solution, etc.).

**Links**

- [Official Node Documentation On Creating A Basic HTTPS Server](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)
- [Blog Post On Creating A Basic Node HTTPS Server With Some Minor Notes On Express.js](http://programmerblog.net/nodejs-https-server/)
- [Another Blog Post On Creating An Extremely Simple Node HTTPS Server With Express.js](https://timonweb.com/posts/running-expressjs-server-over-https/)
- [Express.js Homepage](https://expressjs.com/) and [Express.js 4.x Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

---

**Reverse Proxy With NGINX**

> Someone told me to set up my SSL in nginx and put that in front of the host server. But I have no idea how to do that.

This typically called using a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (where nginx is the proxy server). Per the [official documentation for nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), you would simply need to add something like:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

to the default `nginx.conf` HTTPS server example. So, for instance, modifying the default `nginx.conf` HTTPS server block:

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
#   server_name  localhost;
    server_name  yourwebsite.com;

# Specify where our our certificate files are.
# If we don't specify an absolute path, nginx defaults to searching its "conf" folder

     ssl_certificate      yourwebsite.com.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key  yourwebsite.com.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;

         proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
    }
```

Note that e.g. `http://localhost:81` is your application server. This does not need to be an HTTPS connection (especially if its running on an internal network or nginx is running on the same server) and can theoretically utilize any port (not just 443).

**Caveats**

- When using nginx as a proxy, you may need to take some additional steps (add additional directives) to make sure data and resources are passed between nginx and your application server correctly. The solution to any issue like this may require some additional research.
- If the application (JavaScript) file *only* runs on port 443, you may need to either modify this behavior yourself or set up an additional server or virtual environment (something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), for instance) which also may entail additional configuration or steps.

Comment: However, I noticed you have tagged this question as node.js. Assuming you are trying to run a web application of some sort that uses HTTPS, while it isn't "combining" anything, you would likely need to pass the location of your certificate and key files as variables to the application prior to starting your server to allow the JavaScript file (application) to utilize them for HTTPS transactions. The process of loading or preparing these files for use in your script would depend on how you were creating the application (e.g. Express.js, restify.js, homebrew solution, etc.).

Comment: @kissa-allen The links in my original answer show some (extremely basic) ways to potentially import SSL certificates into a Node.js application. Unfortunately, since the contents of your script are unknown, it's hard to go beyond generic examples. Please note that I have also updated the answer to show a (very basic) example of how you might approach SSL with nginx in front of your application (per your additional comment).

Comment: @kissa-allen Also, if you need further guidance, you can leave additional comments, edit your original question or ask a new one and link to this one.